# How to append to array at certain key

Tags: tcl

I want to know how to append to the contents of a specific key in the array.
Lets say I have a tcl array
`set ARRY(mood) "everything is"`
And I want to add a word to it (lets say, "awesome").
Until now, what I did was taking the value of `$ARRY(mood)` (returns {everything is}), turning it to a string, append the extra word and set it back into ARRY(mood).
How can I add the word directly without all this extra fuss?
It makes no sense the way I'm changing array is the right way to work...

expected contents of ARRY(mood): {everything is awesome}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of an array can be treated as a separate variable and any operation that can be performed on a variable is applicable to it.

```
% set ARRY(mood) "everything is"
everything is
% set ARRY(mood) "$ARRY(mood) awesome"
everything is awesome
% parray ARRY
ARRY(mood) = everything is awesome
%
```

Comment: I knew the way I'm using the array doesn't make sense... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `append` command is designed for this task:

```
append ARRY(mood) " awesome"
```

If it's really a list, `lappend` would work too:

```
lappend ARRY(mood) "awesome"
```

but that's *just* if it is a list. Use `append` for strings, `lappend` for lists.

Comment: excellent answer, even better than the one I selected as the right answer, but the selection was already made.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `append` on the array element:

```
% set ARRY(mood) "everything is"
everything is
% append ARRY(mood) " awesome"
everything is awesome
% puts $ARRY(mood)   
everything is awesome
%
```